# socket did not close after client disconnect JAVA

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, serversocket

Hi I have a code and I want to close the socket whenever the client disconnect from chatting.But whenever client type end, the socket is still alive.
 How am I gonna do this? I tried several tutorials but did not work for me.

here's my code:

```
public void server(){
        Thread serverThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {

                    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

                    while (true){

                        try {
                            System.out.println("Waiting for connection...");

                            socket = serverSocket.accept();

                            System.out.println("New connection established!");
                            System.out.println(username+" is connected");

                            din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                            dout = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                            do {
                                cut = true;
                                read = din.readUTF();

                                if (getForDisplay()!=null){
                                    setForDisplay(getForDisplay()+"\n"+read);
                                }else {
                                    setForDisplay(read);
                                }
                            }
                            while (!read.equals("end"));

                            System.out.println("closed!"); // not working too
                        }catch (IOException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }finally {
                            cut = false;
                            try {
                                cut = false;
                                System.out.println("closed! finally");
                                din.close();
                                dout.close();
                                socket.close();
                            }catch (IOException e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        serverThread.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a

> ```
>   break;
> ```

before closing curly braces of while(true) loop.